# Modifying a read only array and compiler does not throw an error

Tags: c#

I have the below piece of code.

```
public class SimpleStack
{
    private readonly double[] _items;
    
    public void Push(double item)
    {
        _items[0] = item;
    }

}
```

How come I am able to mutate the readonly _items array and the compiler allows it ?

Comment: I get the following when I run your snippet: Run-time exception (line 18): Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Line 18 points to _items[0] = item.

Comment: `readonly double[]` doesn't means that its content is `readonly`. Consider the `double[]` as a pointer, the pointer itself is readonly (i.e., you cannot change where the pointer is pointing to), but the memory that it is pointing to can be changed.

Comment: Thanks a ton imamangoo and gunr2171 i was preplexed by that problem.

Answer (score 5):

It’s the array that is read only, not the *contents* of the array. So you wouldn’t be able to overwrite the array itself after the constructor, but the contents are fair game.